# Chrome Extension: Make it run every page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a chrome extension that executes some scripts after one page is loaded, I am not sure whether I have to implement this logic on the background page or it can be anywhere else, any help here will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just in case, it should run the script after any page is loaded in the browser.

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy yes, just look for content scripts, also make sure that in the run_at option you put document_end and also in matches: you need to specify in which url's your scripts will be injected.

Comment: If you just want to run a script on a page for yourself, you could also do that with [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

From a [background script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) you can listen to the [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onUpdated) event and check the property `changeInfo.status` on the callback. It can be *loading* or *complete*. If it is *complete*, do the action.

Example:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {

    // do your things

  }
})
```

Because this will probably trigger on every tab completion, you can also check if the tab is `active` on its [homonymous attribute](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#type-Tab), like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.active) {

    // do your things

  }
})
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onUpdated' of undefined`

Comment: What? This answer is from 2 and a half years ago. Everything has probably changed now.

Comment: For doing specific url page: `if (tab.url.startsWith("https://example.com") == false) return;`

Comment: @Green Chrome now has Manifest v3 so everything will change even more :)

Comment: As November 2021, using v3, this works perfectly. The `&& tab.active` seems to be unnecessary though.

Comment: only works in an extension!! not the dev console

Answer (score 47):

If it needs to run on the `onload` event of the page, meaning that the document and all its assets have loaded, this needs to be in a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) embedded in each page for which you wish to track `onload`.

Comment: It would be better to let the content script be injected at "document_end" see "run_at" within the content_script manifest: `run_at: "document_end"`

Comment: @MohamedMansour well, it depends… since content scripts are limited to examining the DOM, its co-habitating webpage may have gotten busy earlier, and thus may have permanently mutated or deleted nodes already by that time, which you didn’t get to see and now will never know about..

Answer (score 41):

You can put your script into a content-script, see

- [content-script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Answer (score 40):

This code should do it:

manifest.json

```
   {
      "name": "Alert 'hello world!' on page opening",
      "version": "1.0",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
          ],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ]
    }
```

content.js

```
alert('Hello world!')
```

Comment: is it possible to use regexp in "matches" field?

Comment: Yes, see `https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#matchAndGlob`

Comment: Where did you find the "<all_urls>" token? I couldn't find it anywhere