# Chrome extension how to inject my content script into all Facebook pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My manifest looks like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Facebook Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/fbh.png",
    "default_popup": "fbh-popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "background",
    "tabs",
    "http://www.facebook.com/*",
    "https://www.facebook.com/*"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://www.facebook.com/*", 
        "https://www.facebook.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "js/fbh-main.js"],
      "css": ["css/fbh-main.css"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],

  "background":{
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js","js/fbh-background.js"]
  }
}
```

I want to inject my content script each time I go to a new page within Facebook. For example, if I click on a user's profile I want to inject the content script.

In my background page I have the following listener:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
    console.log(changeInfo);
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "js/fbh-main.js"});
    }
});
```

There are a couple of problems with this, however. First, this function tries to inject my content script into all pages. I need to be able to read the manifest permissions. Second, if I start at www.facebook.com, the content script does what it's supposed to do. But if, from there, I click the profile for "foo" and go to www.facebook.com/foo, the content script IS injected (as evidenced by a console.log message) but it does not do what it's supposed to do. I think it's being injected too soon because if I navigate directly to www.facebook.com/foo, the content script is loaded and does its thing.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497548/chrome-extension-make-it-run-every-page-load) of any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo,tab) {
    console.log(changeInfo);
    if ((tab.url.indexOf("http://www.facebook.com/") !=-1 || tab.url.indexOf("https://www.facebook.com/") !=-1) && changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "js/fbh-main.js"});
    }
});
```

- `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,` will execute script in active tab of Current Window, which may change on user interaction, `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId` will always ensure script injection in tab targeted.
- **`chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener`** will fire for every tab, added filter **`tab.url.indexOf("https://www.facebook.com/")`** to ensure script is injected in face book pages.

Share your manifest ,content script and related files if problem still persist

Answer (score 0):

If your script is executed to soon, you can always use the `$.(your code here);` of jQuery

EDIT : For auto upadate issue, you can simply add a listener in the content script

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(event){
    //something on the page has changed
});
```

Comment: I'm no Chrome Extensions expert, but isn't setting a hard coded timeout for your code kind of a bad practice? Shouldn't you be listening to an event instead?

Comment: Thx, you are right, it was late :p I think the solution here is better.