# Google Chrome extension - How to execute a code once page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an extension to automate some tasks. I'm trying to load a page and then execute a code once the page has been loaded but I couldn't find the right way to do this.

custom.js:

```
var func=function(){

var actualCode = '(' + function() {
    //load the new page
    window.location='http://page.com/'
} + ')();';
    // inserts the code into the current page tab
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code:actualCode})

    //--Execute this code once the page is loaded--

}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click",func);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>  
 </head>
 <body>
  <button id="btn"> BTN </button>
  <script src="custom.js">
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess every time script executed, you're navigated away so your further code will never run.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally done/organized.

Comment: Your current issues would be simplified by changing your `actualCode` to `var actualCode = "window.location='http://page.com/';";` This would at least make it such that your code was doing what you appear to have written it to do (not necessarily what you want it to do, but at least what you have written it to do). However, your question is too broad for this, in and of itself, to be an answer.

Comment: If your *index.html* is a browser action popup, why are you using a button within a popup instead of just a [`browserAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) button?

Answer (score 1):

To track the new page and run any logic on it, one solution could be adding this logic inside a **content script** file that loads at the **document_end** and every time you navigate to the any page using `window.location`, this logic will run.
You may add some conditions to make sure you logic run on the wanted pages/elements.

Am I clear enough?

Comment: Some code would certainly help... it's unclear where this code is placed?

Comment: Ok I will edit the answer ASAP to add some code.. thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I figured it out, I just thought to reply to what is missing in it being super clear :)

Comment: Glad that you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) to check if the page has been fully loaded where status is equal to 'completed'.

Use the code samples which was given in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497548/chrome-extension-make-it-run-every-page-load):

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {

    // execute some codes here

  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Example from docs: you need to modify `manifest.json` to allow extension automatically inject some javascript for websites if urls are matching to the pattern.

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js", "myscript2.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

You can also define `run_at` property to control when the files in js are injected. It can be "document_start", "document_end", or "document_idle".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood well but this should work if I understood well.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",yourFunctionGoesHere)
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not working, I believe that the reason is that when I load the new page it generates a new DOM and this new DOM is not being tracked.