# Injecting external javascript when page loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I want to inject my js function when page loaded and this function will change the page but I want to run same function after page reloaded again and again. Is there any addon on chrome or firefox to make this happen?

Comment: Create a [chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) and put your code in a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: In addition, you have to track the `onload` event in which you or placing this code in your content_script manifest: run_at: `"document_end"`. You can check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6497627/5995040) where this was stated.