# Can't get all 'div' elements from a web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that(for now) changes the background color of elements that have a certain 'class name'.
This code(content script) doesn't work:

```
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('arbitrary-class-name');

for (let el of divs) {
    el.style['background-color'] = 'FFF298';
}
```

I got "Uncaught TypeError: divs is not iterable" when i tried to execute.
I also tried to inspect the source code and i noticed that all the elements that i wanted to get, are dynamically created during loading, maybe my code is trying to access elements that don't exist yet?

edit: [this](https://my-fit.federtennis.it/Tornei/Areas/Federtennis/Scripts/Puc/Tabellone.html?tournamentId=43777&phaseId=65c29a2b-626f-49a9-8a5b-5629bc9f2d79&isDouble=0&printable=1) is the page i'm trying to work with, for instance i want to change the background color of all 'partecipante-info' divs.

edit2: This code always runs after my script:

```
XHR finished loading: POST "https://some-link".
send @ jquery-1.12.4.js:10254
ajax @ jquery-1.12.4.js:9738
(anonymous) @ genera_tabellone_v2.js:15
fire @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3232
fireWith @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3362
ready @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3582
completed @ jquery-1.12.4.js:3617
```

Comment: The `divs` variable should be iterable as `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` which has the iterator protocol. So your `divs` value is something other than a `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: when you use for of is itterable you can work htmlCollection. so you don't find element.

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

If the elements are generated dynamically, you need to run your code after the elements are generated.

You could use a few approaches, but I have 2 suggestions:

1. You could try running the code once, when the page is loaded. Have a look @ the following links. If you want to detect the chrome tab events you could use this: [Chrome Extension: Make it run every page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497548/chrome-extension-make-it-run-every-page-load) . Otherwise you could also try listening for a body onload but I don't know if that would work.
2. Another option would be to use SetInterval and search for the specific elements at specific times. Put this inside the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` and check every 1 second.. when you have found the elements with the specific class disable the setInterval.

### Possible Example

```
   chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
      if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
    
            // do your things
        
        let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('arbitrary-class-name');

        //Check if iterable         
        if(divs == null || typeof divs[Symbol.iterator] !== 'function'){
             return;
        }

        if(di)
        for (elt of divs) {
            elt.style['background-color'] = 'FFF298';
        }
    
    
      }
    })
```

### References

- [Checking whether something is iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884249/checking-whether-something-is-iterable)
- [Chrome Extension: Make it run every page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497548/chrome-extension-make-it-run-every-page-load)

Comment: It seems the problem come from the fact that jquery code is executed after my content.js script, so my code is overwritten.